# Method of Switching an External 5V Signal with a 3.3V Signal

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, dc, level-shifting

I'm designing a system where I need to control the passage of a 5 V signal from one external device to another. This 5 V signal powers circuity but I am currently unable to verify what current this may require or the tolerance on the voltage input. I will eventually be able to test the current but do not have access to this signal yet. I believe it is only circuitry so its safe to assume its <0.5 A.

I need to control the passage of this signal with logic conditions from an Arduino Due output where the outputs are limited to 3.3 V maximum.

I've been looking at accepting this input into the Arduino and then giving a similar output in return. Id rather move away from this option as I would rather avoid the responsibility of providing this power signal and simply use the one provided by this external signal.

As such I've instead been looking at using something like a MOSFET/BJT logic level shifter such as the one in the below diagram. What I need to work out is how passing this signal through this circuit (As the +5V and through to output) will effect the signal. More specifically, am I limited on the current, will I see a voltage drop and is my Arduino capable of driving this circuit (is the current of the Arduino related to my output current or is it simply responsible for saturating the MOSFET only)

Any help / knowledge that can be provided is greatly appreciated!

As a side note, I have considered a DC SSR but I understand they have a voltage drop across the outputs. If you know of any other component that could be used this is a welcome suggestion also.

[image: MOSFET Logic Level Shifter]

Comment: Welcome! Have you looked at commercial level-shifter circuits?

Comment: Hi winny. I have yes. I would have used this with the input to the arduino. But i would like an method that doesnt involve replacing the 5V signal but instead just controls its passage.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "controls its passage". What is your end goal that an off the shelf level shifter won't solve?

Comment: I need to be able to switch on/off the 5V signal using a 3.3V signal from an arduino. I would prefer to avoid editing this signal in any way. So im assuming when using a shifter circuit you would recommend inputting the 5V signal into the arduino and then returning a level shifted 3.3 into 5V signal to essentially replace the 5V signal but now with the control in place.

Comment: Continued comment - This way means the arduino is now driving the external circuitry the 5V usually does and i cant do this from my arduino. Instead i am trying to find a way i can instead either allow the 5V signal through or direct it to ground, such as with the BJT circuit. My main question is am i going to be limiting the 5V signal by doing this. Hope this clarifies this!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to switch 5V @ 0.5 A, that isn't a signal, but a power rail. You want a *high-side* switch.

Q1 should be a *logic-level* N-channel FET.

Q2 is a P-channel FET. It must have a low Rds when Vgs is 4.5 V or so. I would look for something in with an Rds equal to or less than 0.1 ohms. But, without further specifics, this is a guess.

All switches have some voltage drop, you need to design so that the drop is acceptable. 50 mV is usually acceptable, sometimes 100 mV or more is acceptable.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmLj3b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thankyou for the reply! Ill look some more into this and how those FETs work